# Updating filters for OOTB SharePoint 2013 My Site Cleanup Job

Tags: my-site, timer-jobs, cleanup

Is it possible to change the parameters by which the SharePoint 2013 Cleanup Timer Job initiates the process to remove sites/user profiles?

Currently, our internal policies dictate that when a user is on long-term absence (such as long-term sickness, maternity leave, etc), their account is disabled in Active Directory. This, obviously, initiates a flag to remove that users' profile and My Site. However, that person may well return at some point - and they want their site back!

When a user actually leaves the company, their account is disabled AND moved into a "Leavers" OU in Active Directory - it is only these users for whom we wish to remove their profile and My Site (i.e. accounts that have been moved to this OU, not accounts that have just been disabled).

It is possible to alter the Cleanup Timer Job to accommodate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the built-in timer job has no adjustable features. If you need a differing set of parameters, you must build your own process to implement those parameters.

Comment: I agree with Trevor. The OOTB one is not flexible. I built a custom PowerShell script that runs on a schedule to replace the job because my client had issues as well. It's been a couple of years and I don't have the specs now, but the client loved it, so creating something that works is possible. Hope everything goes well for you.

Comment: OK, good to know. If I untick the option "Enable Access Delegation", will this prevent managers from receiving emails (i.e it will still delete the mysite and the profile, but it just won't email the manager)?

Comment: No, the only way to prevent an email going out is to depopulate the UPSA 'manager' property of the departing user.